# In the suggested edits queue, the stack snippet's "Run code snippet" button displays over the review bar

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

It seems in the suggested edits review queue, that the stack snippets run code button will display on top of the review bar (this is the name of the css class) at the top. Can this be fixed?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I'm running the latest version of Chrome (for Windows):
Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)